# How to fix flicker when using transition in Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have the following problem in my current project:

When you hover over the thumbnail images the title of each image fades in. In Safari a short flicker shows up on top of the "title box". I never had a problem like this. I appreciate all suggestions! Thanks for your help.

You can visit the site [here](http://www.ninoustatari.com/beta/projects.html)

Comment: For me the flicker is happening at the bottom of the box. It seems that it's an issue where the white area isn't fully covering the image, looking further into it.

Comment: The white area covers the image fully. In all the other browser it looks just fine. This happens only in safari. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've looked at it a bit more but I can't seem to come up with anything. Maybe you should update your question with some more information about how the hover animation is called and how it works.